# How Call OnDestroy @ AREnvironmentProbeManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit, arcore

In regards to ARFoundation I'd want to give the user the option to switch off AR Env Probes and at OnDisable destroy any trackables/probes created by AREnvironmentProbeManager. Using ARFoundation 3.0 prev.2 Version the probes remain after disabling AREnvProbeMgr.

OnDestroy() in AREnvironmentProbeManager.cs seems to do just this, how can I call this function? It's protected in package: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.AREnvironmentProbeManager.html

"Destroys any game objects created by this environment probe manager for each environment probe, and clears the mapping of environment probes."

Disabling AREnvironmentProbeManager does not destroy probes

```
m_ARSessionOriginGO.GetComponent<AREnvironmentProbeManager>().enabled = false;
//Disables the probe manager but doesn't destroy the probes created.
```

Trying to achieve: Environment probes are destroyed when AREnvironmentProbeManager is disabled.

Comment: [`OnDestroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) is called by Unity via message as soon as the Component or GameObject gets destroyed

Comment: It's probably when it's destroyed. Have you tried `Destroy(m_ARSessionOriginGO.GetComponent<AREnvironmentProbeManager>());` ?

Comment: maybe kind of a hack but alternatively you could also inherit from the according class and add a public method which calls the `OnDestroy`: `public class MyAREnvironmentProbeManager : AREnvironmentProbeManager { public void DoOnDestroy(){ OnDestroy(); } }` when inheriting you have access to `protected` stuff

Comment: derHugo has a fine suggestion here, but just watch out because there may be side effects from calling `OnDestroy()` without actually destroying the thing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch everyone, I ended up finding a workaround that seems to do the trick by subscribing to AREnvironmentProbeManagerScript environmentProbesChanged , creating a list of probes and removing using AREnvironmentProbeManagerScript GetEnvironmentProbe